# imap_open(): Couldn't open stream for hostgator server {mail.mydomain.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in codeigniter

Tags: php, email, imaplib, codeigniter-4

I am working in codeigniter framework using imap library. I want to get all mails from my mail server into my web app.
My code is working fine when i am using

```
imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", my_email, my_password);
```

but whenever I tried to get access of my hostgator mail server I got these type of errors.

```
1: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.mydomain.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX

2: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed. (errflg=1).

3: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed. (errflg=2)
```

Comment: Seems like your authentication failed :/

Comment: yes, but this code is working fine with my gmail account, above errors occur when i try with hostgaotr mail server

Comment: Having a working imap_open with your gmail account is one thing, but using a working imap client (working because it works with your gmail account), against a hostgaotr (?) server, that is actually saying, that your authentication is failing, is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

According the [HostGator Documentation](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/email-connection-settings) you should provide (for secured imap):

1. A username, your full email address
2. Your password
3. Your **full** server name
4. Port: 993
5. SSL: SSL/TLS

You should end up with something like

```
imap_open("{full.servername.com:993/imap/ssl/tls}", "my.email@servername.com","pwd");
```

You could also try the *normal incoming mail settings* which requires

1. A username, your full email address
2. Your password
3. Your **full** server name
4. Port: 143
5. SSL: none

Resulting in:

```
imap_open("{full.servername.com:143}", "my.email@servername.com","pwd");
```

Comment: I tried normal incoming mail setting which you had provided i got this error,
 can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
but if i tried imap_open("{full.servername.com:993/imap/ssl/tls}", "my.email@servername.com","pwd");
i got error like
Message: Unknown: Can't open mailbox {mail.myserver.com:993/imap/ssl/tls}: invalid remote specification (errflg=2)