# unable to connect to hostgator using imap library in codeingiter

Tags: php, imap, codeigniter-4

I tried to get emails from gmail server using imap library

```
$this->conn = imap_open("{".$this->server.":993/imap/ssl}INBOX",$this->user,$this->pass);
```

I got error like:

```
Message: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.server.com:993/ssl}
```

It was start working after I unchecked the less secure apps option from my gmail account and then got emails.

but when i used to get emails from hostgator server i got same error

```
Message: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.server.com:993/ssl}

Message: Unknown: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed. (errflg=2)

Message: Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed. (errflg=1)
```

Like gmail server is their any option that i should check or uncheck in hostgator server. or any other method I should used?

Comment: I'd reach out to their support. You've tried without the directory, and/or read https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/pop3-or-imap-with-ssl?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imap\_open(): Couldn't open stream for hostgator server {mail.mydomain.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323660/imap-open-couldnt-open-stream-for-hostgator-server-mail-mydomain-com993-im)

Comment: no @ManuEidenberger that dosn't work from my side